# Conditionally removing items from a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects `List<Points>` and each object (Points) has some properties such as x, y, and z. (`Points.x`, `Points.y`, `Points.z` are doubles)
I want to delete objects which have some conditions. For example, objects with x<=5, 6<=y<10, z<20 should be deleted. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Search for `LINQ To Objects` and please get back, if your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `points.RemoveAll(point => point.X <= 5 && point.Y <= 6 ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RemoveAll` method like this:

```
list.RemoveAll(p => p.x <= 5 && p.y >= 6 && p.y < 10 && p.z < 20);
```

Comment: RemoveAll is list a method it 's not related to Linq

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq

```
  var pointList = new List<Point>();

  pointList = pointList.Where( p => 
              !((p.X <= 5) && (p.Y > 6 && p.Y < 10) && (p.Z < 20)))
              .ToList();
```

Or another use RemoveAll method on list object

```
   pointList.RemoveAll(p => (p.X <= 5) && (p.Y > 6 && p.Y < 10) && (p.Z < 20));
```

Comment: Thanks. `List<ActivePoints> Points = new List<ActivePoints>();`. Actually I have defined my list in this way (ActivePoints is a class which Points are defined) and each Points has x, y, and z. Can I know what is the meaning of `p =>`? Should I write my code as follows?
`OpenPoints.RemoveAll(p=> p.x <= 5 && p.y >= 6 && p.y < 10 && p.z < 20);`

Comment: p => is Lambda Expressions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If OpenPoints contane all point objects then  RemoveAll will Removes all the objects that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx @KatatoniaSh

Comment: Thank you so much. It will definitely help me to improve my code. One more question. Suppose that if above conditions are satisfied, a field (`Points.w`) of objects which satisfies this condition should take value 1 (`Points.w=1`), otherwise 0 (`Points.w=0`). what is the best way to do this?